# Install El Capitan with VirtualBox on OS X

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am creating an El Capitan Virtual Box on my Mac. This is the process I take. I pressed some keys (it says any) as shown in second image, but I get nowhere. What should I do to move from here?

1. I double click the "El Capitan" option

   [image]
2. This is the screen that opens next.

   [image]
3. This is how I specified the elcap.dmg. This is the dmg file of  `Install OS X El Capitan.app`

   [image]

Nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The dmg file (Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg) is no bootable image.

To create a bootable file use the following script. You may have to modify some paths (i.e. the user name in the last line and the path to Install OS X El Capitan.app (and the inner InstallESD.dmg file) in the 6th line):

```
#!/bin/bash  

# Create bootable El Capitan ISO

# Mount the installer image  
hdiutil attach "/Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/esd

# Create empty cdr image  
hdiutil create -o ElCapitan.cdr -size 8000m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J

# Mount the cdr image  
hdiutil attach ElCapitan.cdr.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/iso

# Restore Base System to the cdr image 
asr restore -source /Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.dmg -target /Volumes/iso -noprompt -noverify -erase

# Remove Package link and replace with actual files  
rm /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/Packages

# Copy Base System  
cp -rp /Volumes/esd/Packages /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation
cp -rp /Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.chunklist /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/
cp -rp /Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/

# Unmount the installer image  
hdiutil detach /Volumes/esd

# Unmount the cdr image  
hdiutil detach /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System

# Convert the cdr to ISO/CD master 
hdiutil convert ElCapitan.cdr.dmg -format UDTO -o ElCapitan.iso

# Rename the ISO and move it to the desktop  
mv ElCapitan.iso.cdr $HOME/Desktop/ElCapitan.iso

# Clean up temporary file
rm ElCapitan.cdr.dmg
```

Paste the content in a text editor to a new document as plain text and save it as prepare_elcapitan_cdr.sh on your desktop.

Open Terminal, chmod the script and execute it:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/prepare_elcapitan_cdr.sh
cd ~/Desktop
./prepare_elcapitan_cdr.sh
```

Detach elcap.dmg from the VM. Use the final ElCapitan.iso as installer iso and attach it to the virtual SATA Port 1. You can delete the ElCapitan.cdr.dmg file.

Comment: Great stuff! Thank you! Do you happen to know what is the appropriate storage space to reserve for this VB? According to https://support.apple.com/kb/SP728?locale=en_US it's 8.8GB. I reserved 30GB and I am still getting an error "There is not enough free space on OS X Base System to install"

Comment: I opened a new question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233823/not-enough-free-space-on-os-x-base-system-while-installing-el-capitan-with-virtu

Comment: @sanjihan Thanks – this question and your other question link above helped me with installing El Capitan in VirtualBox on OS X. Also, [this page](http://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/running-a-mac-vm-on-a-mac-using-virtualbox/) was of help with some problems along the way, including if conversion fails (force eject and run that `hdutil convert` line again) and black screen on boot (change the motherboard chipset to PIIX3 if you have increased RAM from 2 Gb).

Comment: Don't thank me. @klanomath is the real MVP

Comment: That first line in the script fails for me with Sierra. Error is: `hdiutil: attach failed - No such file or directory`. I know the path to the `InstallESD.dmg` is correct because I dragged-and-dropped from the Finder to the Terminal. What is `/Volumes/esd`? Should I have created a volume? My line: `hdiutil attach "/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/esd`

Comment: @BasilBourque In Sierra mounting volumes to /Volumes/ requires root permissions (in contrast to all older systems). You may create mountpoints in your user's realm (e.g. /Users/$USER/Volumes/mnt1) and use these instead

Answer (score 2):

I tested klanomoath's accepted answer to this question using a Mac mini (2018) running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4. I needed to make the following changes.

- I downloaded `InstallMacOSX.dmg` from the Apple website [How to upgrade to OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886). The file was placed in my `Downloads` folder. After downloading, the file needs to be opened with the Finder Application.
- The first command in klanomoath's answer is given below.

  ```
  # Create bootable El Capitan ISO

  # Mount the installer image  
  hdiutil attach "/Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/esd
  ```

  This above command needs to be replaced with the commands given below. A temporary folder named `El Capitan` will be created in your `Downloads` folder.

  ```
  # Create bootable El Capitan ISO

  # Extract the files from the downloaded file
  hdiutil attach "$HOME"/Downloads/InstallMacOSX.dmg
  rm -rf /tmp/El\ Capitan
  pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Install\ OS\ X/InstallMacOSX.pkg /tmp/El\ Capitan
  diskutil eject Install\ OS\ X
  cd /tmp/El\ Capitan

  # Mount the installer image  
  hdiutil attach InstallMacOSX.pkg/InstallESD.dmg  -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/esd
  ```
- The last two commands in klanomoath's answer are given below.

  ```
  # Rename the ISO and move it to the desktop  
  mv ElCapitan.iso.cdr $HOME/Desktop/ElCapitan.iso

  # Clean up temporary file
  rm ElCapitan.cdr.dmg
  ```

  These above commands need to be replaced with the commands given below.

  ```
  # Rename the ISO and move it to the Downloads folder  
  mv ElCapitan.iso.cdr "$HOME"/Downloads/ElCapitan.iso

  # Clean up temporary folder
  cd "$HOME"
  rm -r /tmp/El\ Capitan
  ```
- When executing the command, you may an error message similar to the one given below. The question [System hangs when creating bootable disk drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389216/system-hangs-when-creating-bootable-disk-drive) addresses this error.

  ```
  asr: Couldn't personalize volume /Volumes/OS X Base System
  ```
- I needed to enter the following command before starting the the virtual machine named `El Capitan`.

  > Note: I needed to enter these commands, because El Capitan can not be installed on a 2018 Mac mini. If El Capitan can be installed on your Mac, then you probably do not need to enter these commands.

  ```
  VBoxManage setextradata "El Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "Macmini6,2"
  VBoxManage setextradata "El Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
  VBoxManage setextradata "El Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Mac-F65AE981FFA204ED"
  VBoxManage setextradata "El Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
  VBoxManage setextradata "El Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
  VBoxManage modifyvm "El Capitan" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 06100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
  ```

### References

[forums.virtualbox.org](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=97662&p=473837&hilit=install%20el%20capitan#p473837)