# Anyway to get Mac OS Server to play with in a VM

Tags: mac, osx-server

I work in the IT department at a company that will in the near future be getting a Mac OS Server.

Although I'm not in charge of maintaining the server, I thought it might be beneficial for me to at least get a bit of hands-on experiencing using one.

I was planning on installing it onto a VM (like I would a trial version of Windows Server) and play around with it that way.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: You need Apple hardware to do it within the terms of the license. VMware Fusion or Parallels are the usual way to achieve it on a Mac. Attempting it on anything else is generally off-topic right across Stack Exchange.

Comment: So no way of doing it on a Windows PC? As i don't have a Mac nor do i think i could persuade the finance department for fork out £1200 + just to let 1 guy in IT play with Mac OS Server

Comment: It's theoretically possible, with sometimes insurmountable driver issues... but as it breaks the licensing, SE can't help you. VMWare don't make macOS VMs for the same reason, so you have to cobble it together yourself.

Comment: A Mac in the cloud might be an option. I have no personal experience with such a service, but if you need a Mac for just a few months, the investment for this solution could be more acceptable.

Comment: *Technically* it's possible.  *Legally*... that's another story.  To find out how to install macOS in a VM, have a look at this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290643/install-macos-sierra-on-virtualbox/306694#306694)