# Running OS X El Capitan 10.11 in VirtualBox

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, virtualbox

I need to install OS X El Capitan 10.11 as guest OS in VirtualBox running on macOS High Sierra 10.13. I followed the instructions in [this](https://andypi.co.uk/2016/10/31/mac-osx-el-capitan-on-win-10-virtualbox-host/) guide.

I obtained the OS X El Capitan image from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84m7Z19gucXTFBuMThhWGpVOVU/view) and modified it as outlined in the guide.

On startup I get a kernel/cpu panic and was unable to boot. What is going wrong here? I do not have a original copy of OS X El Capitan 10.11.

How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: You're attempting to boot a VM created by someone else - there's any number of reasons why it doesn't work.  You need to obtain a legitimate installer (from a friend, co-worker, etc.) and then [create the VM yourself](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290643/install-macos-sierra-on-virtualbox/306694#306694).

Comment: What Allan said! I did this a couple of weeks ago following the instructions here: https://github.com/geerlingguy/macos-virtualbox-vm. But you do need to download El Capitain from the Mac App Store. It's a bit fiddly but it does work.

Comment: so this is what i thought - that image in my link + the install guide is for win system.   i was not aware that its possible to download el capitan from the app store without installing it right away