# Should there be a problem making a Time Machine Backup with a sparse disk image containing a bootable installer on my current drive and volume?

Tags: backup, time-machine, ssd, virtualbox

I am trying to make a virtual machine using VirtualBox. I have been following the comment David Anderson made for me here on this post (his comment I am talking about is at the bottom): [Install macOS Sierra on VirtualBox?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290643/install-macos-sierra-on-virtualbox/387404#387404)

I have gotten to his step #3 and finished it. I am now at step 4, but I haven't started step 4.

Before I finished this process I thought it might be a good idea to make a time machine backup of my drive in case I do anything wrong, also I haven't made a backup in about 150 days.

I'm just wondering if making a Time Machine backup with a sparse disk image containing a bootable installer will be a problem for the Time machine backup?

These are my computer specs in case they are needed for reference:

Macbook Pro mid-2014,
Running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (natively)

Comment: Whats the problem with "old fashion" just copy the files to a external drive?

Comment: I don't have an external drive or even a usb thumb drive that is empty and free of storage, so I was cautious of putting the bootable installer or making a new volume on one of those external drives. I don't know if that makes sense, but that's what I decided to go with. Plus, I find it easier to do everything from the drive I am currently running on.

Comment: @Asher do you know the answer to my original question?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with VirtualBox, this doesn't seem like a very safe way to do a backup.  If your in an emergency situation and just need to "backup" things someplace on your computer you might try and borrow a computer from a friend?

Comment: I haven't actually used VirtualBox yet. I only made a sparse disk image that contains a bootable installer. That sparse disk image would then be used to create an ISO file, and once that ISO file is created it would be used in VirtualBox by transferring the ISO file to a virtual machine and then booting up the macOS ISO from there. But I haven't done any of that yet. I only made a sparse disk image and then made a bootable installer on that sparse disk image. The sparse disk image is sitting on my desktop, and it's on the drive I am running from.

Comment: I just want to make a backup of my drive. What's wrong with having a sparse disk image with a macOS installer on it in a time machine backup?

Comment: when you compare the difference of "real files copied" vs "time machine" I just personally prefer not adding "extra software" on top of what should be a simple backup... that and cost sometimes for using iCloud "accidentally"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110765/discussion-between-arlen-and-asher).

Answer (score 1):

I would absolutely encourage you to stop and make a Time Machine backup. There’s no harm in trying to manually twiddle things, but wouldn’t it be better to make your first backup in 150 days to an actual drive that’s connected?

You won’t run into issues with installers being downloaded - those are just are large files that get saved one time and then don’t change in the next hour’s backup.

Comment: Ok thank you for very much for your answer.

Comment: Can you possibly help me make a virtual machine using David Andersons method? Or do you know someone that could possibly help me?

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately. I specialize in VMware and backups and Unix mostly. (And knowing how Apple documents some things)

Comment: Do you know someone that could possibly help me? I don't want to mess up David Anderson's method.

Comment: Good point - no sense auditioning to be a help vampire - always having a second question as soon as one is attempted. I would say let your posts sit for 2 weeks, find others to answer to get reputation to try your first bounty. Or hire someone you like to help guide you if you have more money than time to wait or learn.

Answer (score 1):

At best, Time Machine will preserve the "sparseness" of the "sparse disk image containing a bootable installer" (saving space).  Otherwise, Time Machine will "fill out" the backup to the maximum size of the sparse file.  Which Time Machine does may depend on whether the backup is local or remote (and possibly other factors).  In either case, Time Machine should do its job and backup the file.

However, there are some restrictions on what Time Machine excludes which may affect your Time Machine backup (so YMMV):

https://www.baligu.com/pondini/TM/11.html

For example, if you have excluded your home folder/desktop where the file is located, it will be excluded.

Comment: Would you like to chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111073/room-for-arlen-and-david-anderson

Comment: @Arlen Left some suggestions in the room.